# ToolTip in Grid cell - ExtJs 6

Tags: extjs, grid, tooltip, extjs6

I am using below code to display Tool Tip for Grid cell In ExtJS 6

```
{
header: 'Name', 
cls: 'nameCls',
locked: true,
tdCls: 'nameTdCls',
dataIndex: 'name',
renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip= "' + value + '" data-qclass="tipCls" data-qwidth=200';
    return value;
}}
```

When i run the application it doesnt show the tooltip and display below error message.
[image: JS Console Error on cell mouse hover]

Any idea guys??

Thanks in advance guys.

Regards,
Mahendra

Comment: It seems the tooltip class is missing. Have you called `Ext.QuickTips.init();`?

Comment: @Tyr No i havent call Ext.QuickTips.init(); where should i call this method?

Comment: Call it on `Ext.onReady(function(){ /*here*/ })`

Comment: Hi @Vinod  Gubala.. I tried the same  but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried creating an [Ext.tip.ToolTip](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.tip.ToolTip.html)? You can create a single one to serve as tooltip for each name cell (using `delegate`) and update it with the value of that cell. Set up a grid render listener to create the tooltip like this:

```
render: function(grid) {
  var view = grid.getView();

  grid.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: view.getId(),
    delegate: view.itemSelector + ' .nameTdCls',
    trackMouse: true,
    listeners: {
      beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
        var tipGridView = tip.target.component;
        var record = tipGridView.getRecord(tip.triggerElement);

        tip.update(record.get('name'));
      }
    }
  });
}
```

For a working example, see this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gm1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forget to mention one point that i am using locked grid. In my grid initial 3 columns are locked & remaning are unlocked.                                                                                             For locked columns i have used "locked: true" property. When i put the same in your example it stops working. Any idea why it is not working when i add one column as locked.

Comment: Check the updated [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gm1). A grid behaves differently when using `enableLocking`. The API docs for [enableLocking](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-enableLocking) say this: "A locking grid is processed in a special way. <snip> This Panel becomes merely a container which arranges both in an HBox layout.".

I've changed the example a bit, mostly by moving the `render` listener to `lockedViewConfig`. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Robert Klein Kromhof!

grid columns:

```
columns: [{..., tdCls: 'tip'}]
```

grid listeners:

```
render: function (grid) {
                var view = grid.getView();
                grid.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                    target: view.getId(),
                    delegate: view.itemSelector + ' .tip',
                    trackMouse: true,
                    listeners: {
                        beforeshow: function (tip) {
                            var tipGridView = tip.target.component;
                            var record = tipGridView.getRecord(tip.triggerElement);
                            var colname = tipGridView.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(tip.triggerElement.cellIndex).dataIndex;
                            tip.update(record.get(colname));
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            destroy: function (view) {
                delete view.tip;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create independent function and call when you need.

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('your_grid_id');   // Enter your grid id
initToolTip(grid); // call function

initToolTip: function(grid) {
    var view = grid.view;

    // record the current cellIndex
    grid.mon(view, {
        uievent: function(type, view, cell, recordIndex, cellIndex, e) {
            grid.cellIndex = cellIndex;
            grid.recordIndex = recordIndex;
        }
    });

    grid.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: view.el,
        delegate: '.x-grid-cell',
        trackMouse: true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
                if (!Ext.isEmpty(grid.cellIndex) && grid.cellIndex !== -1) {
                    header = grid.headerCt.getGridColumns()[grid.cellIndex];
                    columnText = grid.getStore().getAt(grid.recordIndex).get(header.dataIndex);

                    tip.update(columnText);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```